# SUM of COST when SKU is like CP% DOMO SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, domo

I'm working with DOMO which is very similar to MYSQL.

I have a table with many columns but there are two important ones: `Item_sku` and `Item_cost`.

Each sku has two letters at the beginning that declare type of item. There are five item types. I'd like the sum of `Item_cost` when `Item_sku` is like `cp%`.

The goal is to see the cost of goods sold for each of the five item types.

Answer (score 1):

Group by first two letters of the Item_sku. Comment out WHERE condition for all items.

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Item_sku,1,2), SUM(Item_cost) FROM item 
    WHERE Item_sku LIKE 'cp%'
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Item_sku,1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to SQL and am just learning it, but I will try to answer.

```
Select sum (Item_cost) 
from table where Item_sku like 'cp%'
```